# C# Modify Connection String that exists inside a library

Tags: c#, wpf, settings, database-connection, connection-string

I have a Class Library, which inside just has a DataSet (MySQL connector) and a Connector class.

I use this class in multiple projects to connect to the database, and I always had the password embedded in the connection string but now I need to be able to modify this string(for security purposes) so I can have the user connect using their own account.

How can I modify this connection string.

I have tried the following

```
Properties.Settings.Default.DataBaseConnectionString = "String";
```

But it seems that the connection string is readonly becase it doesn't appear to have a setter value.

I also tried the following with no luck

```
Properties.Settings.Default.DatabaseConnectionString.Insert(
Properties.Settings.Default.DatabaseConnectionConnectionString.Length - 1,
            "Password=dbpassword;");
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can modify them like this:

```
Properties.Settings.Default["MyConnectionString"] = newCnnStr;
```

For a full solution that also saves the new value to the file, you need to do something like this:

```
    private static void ModifyConnectionStrings()
    {
        // Change the value in the config file first
        var config = ConfigurationManager.OpenExeConfiguration(ConfigurationUserLevel.None);
        const string newCnnStr = "server=(local);database=MyDb;user id=user;password=secret";
        config.ConnectionStrings.ConnectionStrings["MyProject.Properties.Settings.MyConnectionString"].ConnectionString = newCnnStr;
        config.Save(ConfigurationSaveMode.Modified, true);

        // Now edit the in-memory values to match
        Properties.Settings.Default["MyConnectionString"] = newCnnStr;
    }
```

If your dataset is in another assembly, you can still do this providing you make the settings for that assembly public.  To do this:

1. Right-click the project in the solution explorer and click **Properties**
2. Click the **Settings** tab.
3. Change the **Access Modifier** dropdown to "Public", save, and close.

Then you can do this (assuming the other project is called "MyProject.DataLayer"):

```
    private static void ModifyConnectionStrings()
    {
        // Change the value in the config file first
        var config = ConfigurationManager.OpenExeConfiguration(ConfigurationUserLevel.None);
        const string newCnnStr = "server=(local);database=MyDb;user id=user;password=secret";
        config.ConnectionStrings.ConnectionStrings["MyProject.Properties.Settings.MyConnectionString"].ConnectionString = newCnnStr;
        config.ConnectionStrings.ConnectionStrings["MyProject.DataLayer.Properties.Settings.MyConnectionString"].ConnectionString = newCnnStr;
        config.Save(ConfigurationSaveMode.Modified, true);

        // Now edit the in-memory values to match
        Properties.Settings.Default["MyConnectionString"] = newCnnStr;
        MyProject.DataLayer.Properties.Settings.Default["MyConnectionString"] = newCnnStr;
    }
```

Comment: Just updated to account for connection strings for other assemblies (i.e. if you have a data layer project with the datasets in).

Comment: I didn't think using the [] indexer would make it work as I expected it using its value name. You don't understand how much that helped me :) I just finished migrating the database to MySQL for security reasons and couldn't figure out how to use different usernames/passwords in connection string at runtime.

Answer (score 0):

Don't you have the source code of that class?

Also, but a little more complicated method, would be to [patch the assembly](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/msil/reflexil.aspx) using [Reflector](http://www.red-gate.com/products/reflector/) with the [Reflexil](http://sourceforge.net/projects/reflexil/) [AddIn](http://reflectoraddins.codeplex.com/).

Comment: I do have the source code, its my own project. But I cannot figure out how to modify the connection string.

Answer (score 0):

I think you're asking how you can change connectionstring properties at runtime depending on who is using the application.  Hope this helps.

In the past I have done this by making my connection string contain parameters that I can provide using string.Format.

```
    <connectionStrings>
        <add name="SomeDB" connectionString="("Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source={0};Jet OLEDB:Database Password={1}"" />
    </connectionStrings>

string connectionString = string.Format(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["SomeDB"].ConnectionString, location, password);
```

Comment: This seems perfect, but how can I make my dataset and all my adapters connect/reconnect using that string?

Comment: This won't work for `var adapter = new MyTableAdapter()` though, because that will load the values directly from the file.  You'd have to explicitly create Connection objects and set the `TableAdapter.Connection` property each time.

Comment: If you look at Neil Barnwell's answer, you can use the Properties.Settings.Default["MyConnectionString"] and that automatically updates all tableadapters that use that connection string.

Comment: Cool, good to know.  I think I missed that part of your question :/  Regardless I'm glad you have your answer.

Answer (score -1):

It looks like you are loading the connection string from the config file, you should be able to change it from there. Once built it will be a file named the same as your compiled form plus .config. (For example application.exe.config)

Comment: I don't know why I got a down vote, it is possible to modify them at run time but typically for connection strings they are changed infrequently enough that a configuration change outside of the application works.

Not saying it is the best answer but a downvote was harsh IMO

Comment: I didn't downvote you, but you need to read the question more carefully: "I need to be able to modify this string ... so I can have the user connect using their own account."

Comment: That exact string works perfectly for a business centric application with an IT staff to maintain it. Who would have no issue changing XML in a .config file. Or heck it could be set by an installation file, in either case modification outside of your application isn't a bad idea.