# How to use app settings with class libraries on winforms?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, app-config

If I create a app.config for my main app, I can use it using:

```
string test = Properties.Settings.Default.LibTest;
```

Where on the app.config you can find:

```
<applicationSettings>
<RManager.Properties.Settings>
  <setting name="LibTest" serializeAs="String">
    <value>ola lib</value>
  </setting>
</RManager.Properties.Settings>
```

The question is, if I have a class library, is there a way to access the same setting using:

```
string libString = Properties.Settings.Default.LibTest;
```

If not, which solution is the best to access the settings from the main app?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd say that it's not correct if your libruary can get property from the main app. I'd suggest folowing:

Create another static class (f.e. SettingsManager) in libruary (or in some common lib), and after application started fill the data from the appconfig to that common static class (SettingsManager). And that class(SettingsManager) property you can use in your app and in your dll.

If your dll and your app has a lot of bindings, than you should consider taking the source from the dll to exe app, in that case you would be able to access app.config settings.

Comment: by now this appears to be the best solution so far.

Answer (score 0):

Essentially you need to make the settings public and access them from another assembly.

Here's my answers to a couple of previous question that are similar in nature:

- [C# Modify Connection String that exists inside a library](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2592905/c-modify-connection-string-that-exists-inside-a-library/2593123#2593123)
- [Open other program's configuration files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/938585/open-other-programs-configuration-files/938599#938599)

Comment: The first option appears to be better, but how can I read the settings? Like for example the "LibTest" value that I included on the question? Thanks